# URLDownloadToCacheFile Problems

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

--My first question here, please give me a hint If I do something wrong!

I'm using the [**URLDownloadToCacheFile**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775122(v=vs.85)) function in different places of a software project I work for.

1. In the main UI is use this function to update a INI file from the Internet. Here I download the ini file directly with a URL. Works well.
2. In a DLL I use the same function to download a little binary file. This file has exact 308 bytes. It is an encrypted textfile with the ending ".db".

It's this second call that fails.

But this function do not fail on all computers, it just fail on a handfull of computers.

- On my development computer it does not fail.
- On some customer computers it does fail.

But just the one in the DLL. The call in the main GUI does not fail. Any idea? Or more information needed?

```
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToCacheFile(
    NULL,                            //ActiveX component calling this function
    dbUrl,                           //Url to download
    strFileName.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH), //pointer to a string containing the name of the downloade file
    URLOSTRM_GETNEWESTVERSION,       //size of filename buffer above
    0,                               //reserved; must be zero
    NULL);                           //optional IBindStatusCallback
        
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
}
```

Comment: `URLDownloadToCacheFile()` isn't a c++ standard function. Which framework are you using?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is a Windows-specific function (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). More specifically, it is part of the Internet Explorer platform APIs.

Comment: More information is needed indeed. How does the function fail ? If all you can tell is that it returns `E_FAIL`, maybe you should use a `IBindStatusCallback` to monitor progress.

Comment: SirDarius, it always report SUCCEEDED(hr). I have added code to main message. The strFileName is also everytime filled. But no file is written.

Comment: Why are you passing *URLOSTRM_GETNEWESTVERSION* instead of the buffer size (*MAX_PATH*)? And how exactly do you determine, that the file hasn't been downloaded? With filesystem redirection, you may just be looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are trying to run the function on the same thread as the DLL creation. In this case use a different thread inside the dll to run the download function.